# Bluetooth for WindowsCE 5.0 and .NET2.0 with C#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, .net-2.0

I'm looking library, to create Bluetooth connection between my device and other devices.
I want use:

1. .NET2.0 for Windows Mobile
2. WindowsCE 5.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using a particular device, most companies have a useful SDK available with Bluetooth functions/routines.

However, if you're looking for generic abilities across multiple devices you could check out [32Feet.net](http://32feet.net/) or [OpenNetCF](http://community.opennetcf.com/).

Be warned though, that if you're using CE 5.0 the bthutil.dll is not included by default anymore, so many of the functions in 32Feet.net (In the Hand) won't actually work.

Answer (score 1):

Have not done much with it myself (yet), but I've read that *[Mobile in the Hand](http://32feet.net/)* has nice managed libraries that included Bluetooth support.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to go a bit further on what you are wanting to do exactly.

There are many different solutions based on the state of your project, are you already paired with the hand-held and the PC?

Answer (score 0):

I was once able to get Windows Mobile device with .NET Compact Framework 2.0 installed to communicate with PC using [32feet.NET library](http://inthehand.com/files/). You may want to have a look.